$C^{2,\alpha}$ regularity up to the boundary, David Gilbarg , Neil S. Trudiger book
enter image description here
I couldn't understand the conclusion in the last line of the proof. Because if U is locally Hölder in a neighborhood of each point $x_{0}\in T$ ($T\subset \partial \Omega$). Then $U \in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega\cup T)$ .
The book "Elliptic Partial differential Equations of second order" does not mention this argument. I think it's a simple argument but I don't understand it.
I would be very grateful for a solution.

I believe the argument is very simple, that if $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega \cup \mathbb B(x_0, \epsilon))$ for all $x_0\in T$, then $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega \cup T)$

I also believe but why

Because, we can always write $T$ as the subset of a countable union of finite balls... if $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega\cup \mathbb B(x^{(1)},\epsilon))$ and $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega\cup \mathbb B(x^{(2)},\epsilon))$ then $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega\cup \mathbb B(x^{(1)},\epsilon)\cup \mathbb B(x^{(2)},\epsilon))$, and so on......

I've thought about this idea, but we can't always extract a finite undercover to show that $u$ is holder in the union.In the countable case we cannot guarantee that u will be C^{2,alpha} in the union.

Is $\Omega$ bounded? In that case we can use a finite union instead of just a countable one

but the covering is on T, which can be an open of $\partial\Omega$
